Some game on a Boolean function
This is the copy of my question at Mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/476867/some-game-with-a-boolean-function.
Let $f: \{0,1\}^{m + k} \to \{0,1\}^n$ be some function,
where $m = n \log n$  and $k < \log \log \log \log n$.
Consider the following game between Alice and Bob that is determined by $f$, $c_A$ (Alice's capital), $c_B$ (Bob's capital) and some vector $b \in \{0,1\}^n$.
Consider Boolean variables $x_1, \ldots, x_m, y_1, \ldots, y_k$.
Initially all this variables are set to $0$. The  players can change the value of a variable from $0$ to $1$ by using their money. The cost of each such change is equal to $1$.
Bob can change any variable, and Alice can change only $x_1, \ldots, x_m$.
The goal of Bob is to make $f(x_1, \ldots, x_m, y_1, \ldots, y_k) = b$ and the  Alice's goal is the opposite.
A player makes his or her move iff the current value of $f$ does not correspond to his or her goal.
A player looses if he or she spends all his or her money and the current value of $f$ does not correspond to his or her goal.
Let $c_A:= \frac{m}{4}$ and $c_B:=\frac{m}{400}$.
Question Is it true that for every $f$ Alice has a winning strategy for all $b \in \{ 0,1\}^n$ except at most $\frac{2^n}{n}$ values (for large enough $n$)?
Consider the case $k=0$. In this case Alice has a winning strategy for all $b$ except at most $1$ value even if $c_A = c_B$. Indeed, the players have equal opportunities and hence Bob cannot has winning strategy for different $b_1$ and $b_2$ (because Alice also can use one of them).
So, my question is if $k$ is some tiny function, can it dramatically change the situation?
Similar games were considered in 1 2. My question is also related to some problem in Kolmogorov complexity.

Note that simultaneous cross-posting is generally prohibited... maybe check the rules of cs.theory to see if there are exceptions?

The question has been on MO for quite some time with no answer, so it may be ok to repost it here, though the post on MO should at least link here to avoid duplication if it is not deleted. However, what does not make any sense to me is to simultaneously repost the question here and place a bounty on the original question on MO. If you repost the question here, you should ideally delete the question there rather than draw attention to it.
